# iPhone App Delete Badge

Tags: iphone, uikit

I'd like to replicate the visual style of the Springboard's delete badge when you want to delete an application. I've gotten it pretty close, but it's not quite right, and I get the feeling that Apple isn't rendering these on the fly, but rather has a set image that they use.

I was wondering if anyone has done this before, or has such an image, or anything, really :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the little x that is pinned to the top left of the App icon?

As far as I know, it's a PNG that is stored on the iPhone, but of course you have no legal way of getting at the filesystem.

You could always take a screenshot of the iPhone and hack it in Photoshop, but Apple mightn't like that.

Comment: Do you happen to knwo the specific path to it on the iPhone? I'd just like to know the dimensions/properties of it, and then I can create my own with a similar, but not identical, visual style (other applications have done this in the past).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, can't check at the moment. This post might help you though: http://macthemes2.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=184922